# padding zeros to array so I can add arrays of different sizes matlab / octave

Tags: arrays, matlab, octave

I'm trying to pad zeros to arrays of different sizes so I can add them together

Here's some example code of what I'm trying to do.

```
B = repmat(11111, 5, 1)
A= repmat(11, 3, 1)

pad = zeros(abs(length(B)-length(A)), 1)
A_padded = [A; pad] %pad zeros at end
C=B+A_padded

B =

   11111
   11111
   11111
   11111
   11111

>>>A =

   11
   11
   11

>>>pad =

   0
   0

>>>A_padded =

   11
   11
   11
    0
    0

>>>C =

   11122
   11122
   11122
   11111
   11111
```

As you can see zeros get padded to the end of **variable A** which allows me to add different size arrays (A and B) togather.

I'm having trouble adapting the code below to do the same thing any ideas?

```
clear all,clf, clc,tic
phi=(1+sqrt(5))/2;
t_rebuilt=linspace(0,2*pi,8000)
aa_sig_combined_L1=zeros(1,length(t_rebuilt));
a1=1;
kk=0;
phase_L1=0;

for kk=100:-1:0 %work my way backwards 
    phi_inc=phi+kk
    t_rebuilt=linspace(0,2*pi,8000*phi_inc); %
    aa_sig_combined_L1=aa_sig_combined_L1+a1*cos ((phi_inc)*t_rebuilt+(phase_L1)); 

end
```

I'm using octave 3.8.1 which should be compatible with matlab code

Comment: The line t_rebuilt=linspace(0,2*pi,8000*phi); Should have been t_rebuilt=linspace(0,2*pi,8000*phi_inc) I've updated the question

Comment: you know there is an Octave function to do exactly that? Try `postpad`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this edit for the loop-portion of the code works for you -

```
for kk=100:-1:0 %work my way backwards
    phi_inc=phi+kk;
    t_rebuilt=linspace(0,2*pi,8000*phi_inc); %

    %// Get pad length
    padlen = numel(t_rebuilt)-numel(aa_sig_combined_L1);

    %// Pad either of them depending on the sign on `padlen`. 
    %// Thus, negative `padlen` would not pad, but positive would.
    aa_sig_combined_L1 = [aa_sig_combined_L1 zeros(1,padlen)]; %#ok<AGROW>
    t_rebuilt = [t_rebuilt zeros(1,-padlen)]; %#ok<AGROW>

    aa_sig_combined_L1=aa_sig_combined_L1+a1*cos ((phi_inc)*t_rebuilt+(phase_L1));
end
```

Comment: thanks the line t_rebuilt=linspace(0,2*pi,8000*phi); I should have put t_rebuilt=linspace(0,2*pi,8000*phi_inc) but when I change this I get an error operator +: nonconformant arguments (op1 is 1x812944, op2 is 1x804944)

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using Octave, you can use `postpad` which is a function to do exactly that. If you don't know which of the arrays will be longer, `A` or `B`, just pad both and the function won't touch the largest one:

```
octave-3.8.2> A = repmat (11, 3, 1);
octave-3.8.2> B = repmat (11111, 5, 1);

octave-3.8.2> A = postpad (A, max (rows (A), rows (B)))
A =

   11
   11
   11
    0
    0

octave-3.8.2> B = postpad (B, max (rows (A), rows (B)))
B =

   11111
   11111
   11111
   11111
   11111

octave-3.8.2> 
octave-3.8.2> A + B
ans =

   11122
   11122
   11122
   11111
   11111
```

In your specific example, replace the line:

```
aa_sig_combined_L1=aa_sig_combined_L1+a1*cos ((phi_inc)*t_rebuilt+(phase_L1));
```

with:

```
rhs = a1*cos ((phi_inc)*t_rebuilt+(phase_L1));
aa_sig_combined_L1 = postpad (aa_sig_combined_L1, columns (rhs)) + rhs;
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's my suggestion:

```
for kk=100:-1:0 %work my way backwards 
    phi_inc=phi+kk;
    t_rebuilt=linspace(0,2*pi,8000*phi); %
    temp = zeros(1,length(t_rebuilt));
    temp(1:length(aa_sig_combined_L1)) = aa_sig_combined_L1;
    temp = temp + a1*cos ((phi_inc)*t_rebuilt+(phase_L1)); 
    aa_sig_combined_L1 = temp;
end
```

Comment: thanks the line t_rebuilt=linspace(0,2*pi,8000*phi); I should have put t_rebuilt=linspace(0,2*pi,8000*phi_inc) but when I change this I get an error operator +: nonconformant arguments (op1 is 1x812944, op2 is 1x804944)

Comment: That's because `length(aa_sig_combined_L1) > length(t_rebuilt)` when `kk = 99`. It looks like `aa_sig_combined_L1` needs padding until `kk = 98`, and from `kk = 99` onwards, it's the `a1*cos(...)` term that needs padding. @Divakar has proposed a good solution.

Comment: Not bad either, that initial phi part got both of us confused, or rather made it look simple I guess! :)

Answer (score 1):

Matlab (and Octave) have a [padarray](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/images/ref/padarray.html) function ([usage is the same for octave](http://octave.sourceforge.net/image/function/padarray.html)) in there respective image processing libraries. These functions can also be used for non-image data and are probably what you want here.

add the line

`aa_sig_combined_L1=padarray(aa_sig_combined_L1, [0, length(t_rebuilt)-length(aa_sig_combined_L1)], 0, 'post');`

after you recalculate t_rebuilt in the loop. This will calculate the difference in lengths and pad the array with that many zeros after the data. You can change post to pre to pad before the data.

As a side note t_rebuilt doesn't change in your loop so you could move it outside the loop.